# Eliding "auto" keyword in a C++ variadic lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates, auto

I recently found out that this piece of code compiles fine in both GCC and MSVC:

```
auto foo = [](...){
    cout << "foo() called" << endl;
};
```

It takes it any number of any kind of parameters, and simply does nothing with those parameters, so it works as if `auto` was placed before the `...`:

```
// All of these lines will call the lambda function
foo();
foo(100);
foo("Test");
foo("Testing", 1, 2, 3);
```

The C++ reference on [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) does not seem to mention about this, and neither does the page on [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

More surprisingly, this fails to compile:

```
auto foo = [](... x){ // compile error
    cout << "foo() called" << endl;
};
```

Is this behaviour dictated by the standard, and if so, why should the former compile and the latter fail?

Comment: [Variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)

Comment: That explains everything!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just plain old type-unsafe C-style [variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).